# Are there System Dynamic Management Views, Logs, and methods that can be used to diagnose transport-level errors in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, connectivity

I  am getting an intermittent transport-level error in **SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) Version 19.0.2** when executing the following query.

```
set nocount on

BEGIN TRY

    select  SD.OBSVALUE                                         'ServiceDate'
           ,year(SD.OBSVALUE)                                   'SD_Year'
           ,month(SD.OBSVALUE)                                  'SD_Month'
           ,SD.SDID
           ,SD.USRID
           ,SD.PID
    from OBS SD
        left join DOCUMENT D on SD.SDID=D.SDID
    where   SD.HDID = 1000086
            and SD.USRID not in (select Id from cusKnoxExcludeRecords where IdType = 'UsrId')
            and SD.PID not in (select Id from cusKnoxExcludeRecords where IdType = 'PId')

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    
    print N'An error has occurred.'

    SELECT
        SUSER_SNAME(),
        ERROR_NUMBER(),
        ERROR_STATE(),
        ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        ERROR_LINE(),
        ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
        ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        GETDATE()

END CATCH
```

- The error *(below)* is intermittent. The same T-SQL query works for some runs and throws the transport-level error for other runs.
- The `CATCH` is never executed for the `transport-level` error.

```
Msg 1236, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The network connection was aborted by the local system.)
```

I would like to identify the assignable cause(s) of the `transport-level` error. With assignable causes the `transport-level` error is reproducible and a solution is possible.

### Are `transport-level` errors logged?

Ideally, there should be some useful information on the `transport-level` error somewhere. The date and time stamp on such messages could be helpful to cross-reference issues other logged issues.

There is no shortage of articles discussing different types of `transport-level` errors. Most point out that this is a connection error and offer a laundry list of potential solutions. For example:

> ...because there was a problem with connecting to the server.

What worked for one may not work for all.

It is possible to try every item in the laundry list and not solve the problem. This is because the solution for this instance is not in list or the problem is caused by the combination of two or more factors. When issues are caused by combinations of two or more factors the causes will not be identified by testing solutions one-factor-at-a-time.

Data and a diagnostic procedure would be useful for removing the guesswork.

### Questions

1. Are there existing procedures that can concisely identify the causes of transport-level errors (or connection issues)?
2. Is there useful data on intermittent transport-level errors that is logged on the server or workstations? I have searched the following and have not found any information on transport-level errors:

a. The SQL Server Error Log at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\`

b. I have not found entries in The Event Viewer that logs `transport-level` errors.

c. SQL Dynamic Management Views. So far the only place I see the error is in the SSMS Messages pane.

d. SQL Server Management Reports - The "Number of Errors" reports

> ...Currently, there are no errors on this instance.

3. Is it possible to catch and log transport-level errors in a .NET application?
4. Ping and Ping Plotter do not show any obvious connection issues.
5. We replaced network cables and checked network adapters.

Comment: PingPlotter and (Windows) `ping` use ICMP to test connectivity which may take an entirely different route across the internet than TCP and/or be subject to different routing priorities and QoS rules. Have a read through the introductory [Differences Between TCP, UDP, and ICMP article](https://www.pingplotter.com/wisdom/article/packet-type-differences) on PingPlotter's site.

Comment: I believe this is a client-side (SSMS) error which would be why it's never caught in the try-catch block on the SQL Server side - and why there's [no message_id 1236 in the sys.messages view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors-1000-to-1999). Are you perhaps using a VPN or SSH tunnel along the network path from SSMS to the SQL Server?

Comment: Side note: that `CATCH` is awful, as it's just going to swallow the errors and return a resultset. Just remove it entirely.

Comment: Agree - the `CATCH` is never executed. Kind of pointless...

Comment: It's not pointless because it is never executed. It is pointless as it adds no value and is actually harmful as it hides the errors rather than bubbling them up as errors

Answer (score 1):

> SQL Server 2008 contains a new feature designed to help troubleshoot
> particularly tricky connectivity problems. This new feature, the
> Connectivity Ring Buffer, captures a record for each server-initiated
> connection closure, including each kill of a session or Login Failed
> event. To facilitate efficient troubleshooting, the ring buffer
> attempts to provide information to correlate between the client
> failure and the server’s closing action.

[Connectivity troubleshooting in SQL Server 2008 with the Connectivity Ring Buffer](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/connectivity-troubleshooting-in-sql-server-2008-with-the/ba-p/383393)